# Cesium: Can I overlay terrain with image, then have slopeRamp material on top of that?

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm starting out with the [Sandcastle Globe Materials example](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Globe%20Materials.html) looking at the slope, then by changing the context fillRect alpha to 0.5, I can get it to show the terrain imagery underneath the slope coloring. It looks alright, but I want to just show the pure slope in certain areas.

What I'd like to do is be able to mask the underlying imagery, and substitute the slope for that, but then still have slope with 0.5 alpha on areas outside of the mask.

Failing that, I could overlay a png that's white in the areas to be highlighted, and then overlay the slope material on top of that. But I'm not sure if that's how materials work. It seems like materials are at the bottom, and then you can overlay imagery on top of that.

Here's [image: the look I've achieved before] the look I've achieved before with Photoshop. You can probably tell it's a ski area, and the trees are overlaid with alpha onto a slope map. But I had to make my own slope map which is tedious. Cesium already does the slope, I just want to do the masking.